# What color are Ron's eyes?

Tags: harry-potter, ron-weasley

We know the color of both Harry's and Hermione's eyes but what color are Ron's eyes? Was it ever stated in the books?

Comment: I randomly found [the answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/20633/46611) to this in the related questions list.

Comment: This is addressed in the linked (dupe) answer. Ron's eyes are blue.

Comment: I feel like this is a separate enough question that it warrants its own answer. Reopening.

Comment: @Mooz Don't really like the long-running site policy that answers make dupes, but unless that policy has been overturned and nobody told me, it seems like we can't really act capriciously

Comment: @Au101 I don't think that site policy looks only at answers when judging whether questions are duplicates. See [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9748) answer by Shog.

Comment: @Amaranth - the purpose of duping against answers is that it prevents worthless duplication. The answer to this question is found elsewhere and here. Now we have two.

Comment: @Valorum Bring it up on meta if you care.

Comment: @Amaranth - Nah. Not bothered. I look forward to a question about Hermione's eyes shortly.

Answer (score 32):

### Blue

> MA: What color are Ron's eyes?
>
> JKR: Ron's eyes are blue. Have I never said that, ever? [JKR covers
> her eyes.]
>
> MA: They’ve been dying for us to ask this.
>
> JKR: Blue. Harry's green, Ron's blue, and Hermione's are brown.

Source: Melissa Anelli and Emerson Spartz. ["The Leaky Cauldron and Mugglenet interview Joanne Kathleen Rowling: Part Three"](https://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/07/28/jkrhbp3/), The Leaky Cauldron, 16 July 2005

(found via [accio quote](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-tlc_mugglenet-anelli-3.htm))

Answer (score 20):

It was stated in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows (when they were destroying the Horcrux locket) that Ron's eyes are blue.

Harry thought he saw a glimpse of scarlet in Ron's eyes, but when the Horcrux died the narrator said they...

> ... were no longer red at all, but their normal blue.
>
> <sub>Chapter Nineteen: The Silver Doe</sub>