# Is the Hogwarts entrance letter written in the color of the receiver's eye?

Tags: harry-potter

Reading the first few chapters of *the Sorcerer's Stone*, I became very curious about the Hogwarts letter over these lines.

> - ...and the address was written in emerald-green ink.
> - ...held up the letter so [the Dursleys and Harry] could read the green ink address...
>
> (both from Chapter 3, *The Letters From No One*)
>
> - ...the yellowish envelope, addressed in emerald green...
>
> (Chapter 4, *The Keeper of Keys and Grounds of Hogwarts*)

We can see that the address of the letter that Harry received was written in emerald-green ink, which is also his eye color. However, I couldn't find out whether the letter inside the envelope was also written in green. I wonder if we can infer from this that young wizards and witches get their Hogwarts letter written in the same color ink as their eye. For example, would Ron have gotten his letter written in blue ink? If they do, the question will be How. Oh, and how will odd-eyed people's letter be like, if their right and left eye's color is different?

Comment: The letter is written by McGonagall. While she _could_ have known that Harry's eyes were green, I doubt she could know other students eye colours, given she's never seen them.

Comment: Were the Gryffindor Quidditch robes modelled on Voldemort's eyes or do they just so happen to both be red...?

Comment: I have blue eyes, and about half of the hand-written correspondence I’ve received has been written in blue ink. The other half of the time they use black ink to match my pupils. So yes, your theory must be correct.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

School letters (presumably from the desk of the Headmaster and Deputy Headmistress) are written in green ink as standard. Ron gets one too, as do his brothers.

> ‘Letters from school,’ said Mr Weasley, **passing Harry and Ron
> identical envelopes of yellowish parchment, addressed in green ink.**
> ‘Dumbledore already knows you’re here, Harry – doesn’t miss a trick,
> that man. You two’ve got them, too,’ he added, as Fred and George
> ambled in, still in their pyjamas.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets: CHAPTER FOUR — At Flourish and Blotts</sup></sub>

Since we know that [Ron's eye colour is blue](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155860/what-color-are-rons-eyes), the theory that the letters are written in the recipient's eye colour is disproven.